# Is it still valid to ask for "buy me a coffee" / "tip" payment through Android application?

Tags: android, paypal

It has been asked before but most of those answers are probably outdated.

I am thinking in integrating Paypal api (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/) for my android application.

It is a link that says - Buy me a coffee, which will lead through the process of making a payment using above JAR.

Before I implement so, I have heard that many have some problem where Google has taken their application out of the market because it uses someone else payment option.

Also, any thoughts on https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/donations

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, any thoughts on https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/donations

Here goes note taken right from the README:

> NOTE: Google mailed me to remove PayPal donation capability when publishing on Google Play! Thus, you should build "product flavors" defined by the example: One version with Google Play donation capability and one with Paypal, Flattr, and Bitcoin!

Which means that Google is against PayPal donations in the apps loaded into the Google Play Store.

I've read the [Developer Policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) and it looks unclear. On one hand they say that all purchases in Android apps available on the Google Play Store should be made via Google Play Billing API. On the other hand, they say nothing about the donations (which differ from purchases in my opinion because user gets nothing for donation).

I would not risk the app's status and make donations via Billing API - after all, the main reason why Google bans apps which use 3-rd party billing is that Google doesn't get money from 3-rd party billing. If this is the case than you should be safe if you stay away from PayPal.

Comment: Thank you but then why Paypal would even bother giving us an option on Paypal api - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Comment: @codebased developer policy says there're two exceptions when you don't need to use Billing API: 1) when you sell non-digital content in your app, 2) when you sell digital content which can be used outside of your app (e.g. music which can be downloaded and played in some music-player). You can use 3-rd party billing libraries in these cases.